# Winlicense with hardware lock of Windows exe

Tags: c++, obfuscation, source-code-protection

I have a Windows exe file, which I want to make hardware-locked. I want it to run only on computers, which have a valid license key. For this I use Winlicense.

I created a project in Winlicense and all is OK, but when I click "Protect" the protection finishes successfully, but the exe is running without any problems on any Windows computer. I expect to see a message that this program requires a valid key in order to run.

I can send the XML of my Winlicense project together with the exe file (the exe file is absolutely empty).

What is the right way to protect the exe, so that it asks for a valid key when it is run?

Comment: I think you should contact Oreans support for this.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote to them, but no answer yet. I am just wondering if I am doing it correctly. If you have previously protected exe files with Winlicense maybe you can send me your XML file to check what I am doing wrong?